# QGIS coordinates don't change even after changing CRS, points all overlap

Tags: mapping, qgis

I am trying to create a map of hydroelectric plants in China. I downloaded the shapefile from [here](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/DBJ3BX), added it as a vector layer, then added a CSV with latitude/longitude coordinates for the plants. All I saw was one dot in the center of the country. I zoomed in and saw that all the points were there, but they weren't matching the coordinates of the shapefile. (See screenshots.) When I hover over the points I see the proper coordinates, but when I zoom out, the coordinates look huge.

I changed the CRS of both the CSV and the shapefile to the same thing, EPSG:4326. I then exported it as a new shapefile with a .prj file included. This did not help. How do I shrink down the shapefile of China so that it matches the coordinates of the CSV?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your shapefile is not in 4326 and you have lied to Qgis by saying it is. Set the correct projection on the shapefile and Qgis will take care of the reprojection for you.

Comment: How do I figure out what the correct projection is?

Comment: look at the metadata or ask the supplier